# JPA Exception - More than one row with the given identifier was found: 4, for class: com.study.expensecalculator.entity.Expense

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

Below query is not getting applied -

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "select e.expenseid, e.expensedetails, e.amount, e.createddate,e.comment, c.*, p.* from Expense e inner join Category c on e.categoryid = c.categoryid inner join Payment p on e.paymenttypeid = p.paymenttypeid where c.categorytype = 'Expense'")
    List<Expense> findAllRecords();
```

JPA returning below query -

```
select expense0_.expenseid as expensei1_1_2_, expense0_.amount as amount2_1_2_, expense0_.categoryid as category6_1_2_, expense0_.comment as comment3_1_2_, expense0_.createddate as createdd4_1_2_, expense0_.expensedetails as expensed5_1_2_, expense0_.paymenttypeid as paymentt7_1_2_, category1_.categoryid as category1_0_0_, category1_.categoryname as category2_0_0_, category1_.categorytype as category3_0_0_, payment2_.paymenttypeid as paymentt1_3_1_, payment2_.paymenttype as paymentt2_3_1_ from expense expense0_ left outer join category category1_ on expense0_.categoryid=category1_.categoryid left outer join payment payment2_ on expense0_.paymenttypeid=payment2_.paymenttypeid where expense0_.categoryid=?
```

Expense pojo -

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "expense")
public class Expense {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int expenseid;
    @Column(nullable = true)
    private String expensedetails;
    private Double amount;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonManagedReference(value = "expense")
    @JoinColumn(name="categoryid")
    private Category categoryExpense;

    private String comment;
    private Date createddate;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonManagedReference(value = "expense")
    @JoinColumn(name="paymenttypeid")
    private Payment paymentExpense;

}
```

How the native query mentioned inside @Query annotation will be applied? As per my understanding that query will resolve the runtime exception

Comment: @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false) --> helped to form inner join query as below but error still persists

Comment: select e0_.expenseid as expensei1_1_2_, e0_.amount as amount2_1_2_, e0_.categoryid as category6_1_2_, e0_.comment as comment3_1_2_, e0_.createddate as createdd4_1_2_, e0_.expensedetails as expensed5_1_2_, e0_.paymenttypeid as paymentt7_1_2_, c1_.categoryid as c1_0_0_, c1_.categoryname as category2_0_0_, c1_.categorytype as category3_0_0_, p2_.paymenttypeid as paymentt1_3_1_, p2_.paymenttype as paymentt2_3_1_ from expense e0_ inner join category c1_ on e0_.categoryid=c1_.categoryid inner join payment p2_ on e0_.paymenttypeid=p2_.paymenttypeid where e0_.categoryid=?